# Xubuntu 13.10 - Sound indicator missing

Tags: audio, xubuntu, xfce4

This topic refers not (!) to the [already known bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360806/volume-indicator-issue-after-xubuntu-13-10-upgrade).

I can't add the sound indicator to my xfce4 bar. There is no such item in the items list.
And also - I have no icon for sound management in my system settings.

How to add the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a Sound icon in Xubuntu 13.10 System Manager, instead just right-click the Audio Mixer applet in the panel and change the sound settings from there. To change the sound settings first install xfce4-mixer and then add the Audio Mixer applet to the panel.

Xfce4-mixer is the front-end for mixer settings delivered together with the Xfce4 desktop environment. It does the same jobs other mixer front-ends do, but is integrated into the Xfce4 desktop as a plugin for the Xfce4 main panel. To install xfce4-mixer from the terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-mixer
```

Right-click on the panel and choose *Panel* -> *Add New Items*. From the **Add New Items** window, add the Audio Mixer applet, or drag the Audio Mixer applet icon from the Add New Items window to the panel.